# Boot hangs after I have moved home partition

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, home-directory

I have a Dell Inspiron with pre-installed Ubuntu 11.10. It has a huge root partition without swap, home etc. I have decided to repartition the system. Since I did not want to delete dellutility and os partitions, I have resized the root (`sda3`) partition to smaller and then I have created an extended partition (`sda4`) with 3 logical partitions for home (`sda5`), storage (`sda6`) and swap (`sda7`). I could modify `fstab` so after boot storage and swap are there and working.

Then I followed [this description](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move `home` from root to the logical partition. I could reboot after step 2 then I could successfully `rsync` home content, and modify `fstab` again. After step 5 I have rebooted but even the grub menu does not appear what was there before. 
I did not modify anything related to grub during these steps.  The 512 bytes of MBR looks as before.
Booting from USB shows that there are no changes in `/var/log` at all.
I have checked the UUIDs in fstab and they match the ids what blkid shows. 
I have moved `/old_home` back to `/home` and I have deleted all the new lines from `fstab` but the system still does not boot.

What is wrong with my procedure?

As it is a new machine there is nothing important in home I just want to have a separate partition before I start using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no answer here I asked the same question at [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12429037). 
The solution was to reinstall grub from a live usb like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```